# How to convert an MySql query to Linq with count and attributes

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

i need some help here, want to show a list with columns as follow: numpet, NombreAyuda, TipoAyuda how can i do this with linq?

```
 SELECT count(a.idAyuda) AS numpet, 
        a.NombreAyuda, 
        a.TipoAyuda
FROM PeticionCiudadano AS p
JOIN Ayuda AS a ON (p.idAyuda = a.idAyuda)
GROUP BY p.idAyuda
ORDER BY numpet desc;
```

I have this but i dont know how to show the attribute of name(a.NombreAyuda)

```
 var listaAyudas = (from p in DB.PeticionCiudadano 
                    join a in DB.Ayuda on p.idAyuda equals a.idAyuda 
                    group p by p.idAyuda into g 
                    select new {numPet=g.Count(), name=g.Key});
```

Comment: Since you are not grouping by `a.NombreAyuda` or `a.TipoAyuda`, is that SQL even valid? Surely the only non-aggregate column you can `select` is `p.idAyuda` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that SQL works in mysql (it doesn't in SQL Server), then it works by inferring some additional parts of the `group by` clause based on the `select` columns and the join direction. The more explicit SQL would be:

```
SELECT count(a.idAyuda) AS numpet, 
        a.NombreAyuda, 
        a.TipoAyuda
FROM PeticionCiudadano AS p
JOIN Ayuda AS a ON (p.idAyuda = a.idAyuda)
GROUP BY a.NombreAyuda, a.TipoAyuda
ORDER BY numpet desc;
```

which should be a big clue how to fix it: group by those columns explicitly:

```
var listaAyudas = (from p in DB.PeticionCiudadano 
                join a in DB.Ayuda on p.idAyuda equals a.idAyuda 
                group p by new { a.NombreAyuda, a.TipoAyuda } into g 
                select new {
                        numPet=g.Count(),
                        g.Key.NombreAyuda,
                        g.Key.TipoAyuda
                });
```

Note that you might need to add an `orderby` clause too.

Comment: Thanks again, i've solved the orderby thing when i'm showing the list foreach(var o in listaAyudas.OrderByDescending(f=>f.numPet)